# Batch file that opens an ini file with username and password credentials

Tags: file, batch-file, ini

I am trying to open an ini file on a remote machine with.....

```
start notepad \\%IP%\c\%path%\filename.ini
```

The problem I have is that it needs a windows username and password.

When I browse to \192.168.1.X\ it requires me to login, which I can. I need the batch file to be able to do this as well.

I will also need to copy a few other files to that IP to a few different locations.

Comment: Have you considered using `net use` to map the drive first? You will still need a username and password, but you'll be able to specify them in the batch file, or as parameters to the batch file.

Comment: look at the `net use` command.  It allows creating and destroying drive letters - and it allows you to specify a username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try mapping the share with the `net` command:

```
net use R: \\%IP%\c %password% /USER:%username%
if errorlevel 1 goto :eof
start notepad R:\%path%\filename.ini
```

When you are finished you can run:

```
net use R: /DELETE
```

The only thing I'm concerned about here is that because you're using the `start` command, you can't clean up the mapped drive, otherwise it might disappear before notepad can open the file.  And you wouldn't be able to save it.

Perhaps you would consider splitting this into a script that sets up a mapping and another script that does the required actions.

For more information, type:

```
net help use
```

Comment: I had to modify it a little bit because I was running my batch file in a folder that would path to that folder so I had to use c:\windows\system32\net use .......
I was actually trying this before but i was not setting a drive letter.

Also with my batch file there is enough in between where deleting is not an issue otherwise you could just throw in a pause before deleting.

Comment: You can do this without setting a drive letter, by supplying `*` instead of the letter.  However, this increases the complexity, because you need to use the `FOR /F` command to process the result (`NET` informs you which drive letter is used, if successful).  I decided not to include details for this.